# Kubernetes Persistent Volume for Pod in Production

Tags: kubernetes, sqldatasource, kubernetes-pod

I executed a scenario where I deployed Microsoft SQL Database on my K8s cluster using PV and PVC. It work well but I see some strange behaviour. I created PV but it is only visible on one node and not on other workers nodes. What am I missing here, any inputs please?

Background:

Server 1 - Master

Server 2 - Worker

Server 3 - Worker

Server 4 - Worker

Pod : "MyDb" is running on Server (Node) 4 without any replica set. I am guessing because my POD is running on server-4, PV got created on server four when created POD and refer PVC (claim) in it.

Please let me know your thought on this issue or share your inputs about mounting shared disk in production cluster.

Those who want to deploy SQL DB on K8s cluster, can refer blog posted by Philips. Link below,

https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/sql-server-on-linux-on-kubernetes-part-1/ (without PV)

https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/sql-server-on-linux-on-kubernetes-part-2/ (with PV and Claim)

Regards,
Farooq

---

Please see below my findings of my original problem statement.
Problem: POD for SQL Server was created. At runtime K8s created this pod on server-4 hence created PV on server-4. However, on other node PV path wasn't created (/tmp/sqldata_.

- I shutdown server-4 node and run command for deleting SQL pod (no replica was used so initially).
- Status of POD changed to "Terminating" POD
- Nothing happened for a while.
- I restarted server-4 and noticed POD got deleted immediately.

Next Step: 
- I stopped server-4 again and created same pod.
- POD was created on server-3 node at runtime and I see PV (/tmp/sqldata) was created as well on server-3. However, all my data (example samples tables) are was lost. It is fresh new PV on server 3 now.

I am assuming PV would be mounted volume of external storage and not storage/disk from any node in cluster.

Comment: You'll need to post your kubernetes configuration and any errors you see to get much useful help.

Comment: Hi Paul, I am not getting error rather noticing K8s behaviour that is not very clear. I created PV and refer it in my POD. However, that PV is not visible on other nodes so I wonder if server, where POD is created by K8s, goes down and POD go created on other active node, it may not have view of old data.

Answer (score 2):

> I am guessing because my POD is running on server-4, PV got created on server four when created POD and refer PVC (claim) in it.

This is more or less correct and you should be able to verify this by simply deleting the Pod and recreating it (since you say you do not have a ReplicaSet doing that for you). The `PersistentVolume` will then be visible on the node where the Pod is scheduled to.

Edit: The above assumes that you are using an external storage provider such as NFS or AWS EBS (see [possible storage providers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes) for Kubernetes). With `HostPath` the above does NOT apply and a PV will be created locally on a node (and will not be mounted to another node).

There is no reason to mount the `PersistentVolume` also to the other nodes. Imagine having hundreds of nodes, would you want to mount your `PersistentVolume` to all of them, while your Pod is just running on one?

You are also asking about "shared" disks. The `PersistentVolume` created in the blog post you linked is using `ReadWriteMany`, so you actually can start multiple Pods accessing the same volume (given that your storage supports that as well). But your software (a database in your case) needs to support having multiple processes accessing the same data.

Especially when considering databases, you should also look into [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/), as this basically allows you to define Pods that are always using the same storage, which can be very interesting for databases. Wherever you [should run or not run databases on Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/to-run-or-not-to-run-a-database-on-kubernetes-what-to-consider) is a whole different topic...

Comment: Thank you for your response Simon. I wonder what will be behaviour of cluster if I delete POD and also take server 4 down. If K8s create POD on other node, say for example, server 2 or 3, my pod won't have old data because data was written on PV that was created on server 4 by K8s. What I am not clear is mapping of PV   with K8s clusters. My understanding is that PODS can come and go on any nodes, if that is the case how PV can be visible to POD on all nodes so application don't lose data (in my case is SQL DB with no replica, for instance).

Comment: That is a good question and will heavily depend on the storage you are using for your PVs. There are a lot of different types of PVs available: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes Typically, the storage is independent from the nodes and Pods, which would mean that the PV will still contain all the data, even when nodes are down. But from your description I am guessing you are using "HostPath"? In that case you are correct, the Pod can only run on Node 4. To have a PV that can be used on all nodes, use a different type of PVs.

Comment: Hi Simon, you're right. I am using host path in virtual machine. I post yaml file for creating PV and later found path was created on Node-4 because POD was created on Node-4. I think in case of non-external PV (example host), it is decided by Master and randomly create on available node at that time. In my case it was node-4 (and not all nodes such as node-2, 3, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I added this information about HostPath to my answer above, as this is expected. In your case, you can investigate on how to use external storage providers (such as NFS, AWS EBS, ...)